How to make Webpack 5 bundle more verbose
I'm using Webpack (v.5.92.0) with Node.js (v.20) and when I import a module which I forget to include into html with <script> tag (I don't use generating html file) then I don't get any error about missing JS module.
Is there a way to make the JS bundle more verbose to make an error/warning/notice about missing imported file?
Example of entry point file main.js:
import _ from "lodash";

console.log(_);

DevTools Console after run main.js after not including <script src="lodash.js"></script>:

I tried dynamic imports - it's working very well but it's not helpful in every case .
I expect an error message in DevTools Console when there's missing a module.
I don't expect CLI logging/debugging while building a bundle.
